# looping through databse in my sql to get all results and displaying them

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables users and msgs :
`users` contain `id`,`name`,`email`,`password`
and `msgs` contains `id`, `sender`, `receiver`, `link`
i want to select all the rows where receiver is equal to the same id of the user how can i loop it to get them all ?

i try doing something but nevermind

```
$name_query = mysql_query("SELECT fullname,id FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
$name = mysql_fetch_object($name_query);

$user_id = $name->id;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT receiver FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
}

mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

Comment: you might want to consider sanitising your `$email` and `$user` variables, too

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
Select 
u.fullname,u.id
from 
`users` u
INNER JOIN msgs m ON (u.id=m.receiver)
WHERE email = '$email'
```

Comment: i did and then what do i echo ?

Answer (score 0):

You should only retrieve the lines you want, not all the lines (what if you have 1.000.000 messages in your database ?).

This can be done with only one query using "JOIN" : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

use [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) clausule

```
SELECT m.*, u.email, u.name FROM `users` AS u
JOIN `msgs` AS m ON m.receiver = u.id
WHERE u.email = '$email'
```

this gives you e.g.

```
| id | sender | receiver |   link   |      email       |      name       |  
+----+--------+----------+----------+------------------+-----------------+
|  1 |    1   |     2    |   adfd   | receiver's email | receiver's name |
```

you can fetch result to associative array and use named indexes like:

```
$row['link']
$row['name']
```

or to normal indexed array (correct indexes you can find out by printing whole array)

```
print_r($row)

$row[3] // should be link
$row[5] // should be name
```

Comment: u'll get columns from 2 tables in one row (one record)

Comment: allright now the 2 tables are merged now if i wanna echo the name of the user and the link how do i do that ?  thank you for your help

Comment: can i do that ?  
`$sql = mysql_fetch_assoc("SELECT m.sender,m.receiver, m.link, u.name, u.email FROM `users` AS u JOIN `messages` AS m ON m.receiver = u.id WHERE u.email = '$email'");`

and then $row['name'];

Answer (score 0):

Loop in your case is much costly and not useful. Use `LEFT JOIN` (JOIN or INNER JOIN will return nothing if any column is NULL);

```
SELECT 
  u.*,
  m.sender, m.receiver, m.link
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN msgs m ON (m.receiver = u.id)
WHERE email = '$email'
```